# window.addEventListener freezing browser with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

This is my first time with React and I don't understand why this code is like freezing the browser (I'm using Chrome) when clicking multiple times on the window

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [window_touched, setWindow_thouched] = useState(0);
  window.addEventListener("click", () =>
    setWindow_thouched(window_touched + 1)
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {`This window has been thouched ${window_touched} times`}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're registering an event handler every time the component is rendered; Don't do that.

Comment: And how should I do? Should I delete it every time or what?

Comment: @isGonzito - I suggest reading through the [React website](https://reactjs.org), starting with the Tutorial. It covers all of this stuff in a fairly concise way. It'll save you a lot of time vs. just playing around with things trying to figure them out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? What functionality are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way to do it than listening for events on the whole window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a function component is executed **every time** the component is rendered. You're constantly adding additional event handlers, never cleaning up the old ones.

Instead, add the handler once when the component is mounted, and remove it when the component is unmounted, using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) callback with an empty dependencies array and a [cleanup callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect):

```
function App() {
    const [window_touched, set_window_touched] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = () => {
            set_window_touched((touched) => touched + 1);
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", handler);
        return () => {
            // This is the cleanup function
            window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {`This window has been touched ${window_touched} times`}
        </div>
    );
}
```

(I used the name `set_window_touched` instead of `setWindow_thouched` because A) I wanted to fix the typo, and B) To use snake_case consistently. Note, though, that the usual convention would be to use `windowTouched` and `setWindowTouched`.)

Note that that uses the [callback version](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `set_window_touched`, passing in an update function that receives the up-to-date version of `set_window_touched` and returns the new value to set. That's because the handler is only created the *first* time the component is mounted, which means if it used `window_touched` directly, it would only ever see the value from the first call to `App`, which would always be `0`.

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
    const [window_touched, set_window_touched] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = () => {
            set_window_touched((touched) => touched + 1);
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", handler);
        return () => {
            // This is the cleanup function
            window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {`This window has been touched ${window_touched} times`}
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Instead of that template literal, the more standard way to include text with placeholders in React the majority of the time is to just do it in the JSX:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        This window has been touched {window_touched} times
    </div>
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
    const [window_touched, set_window_touched] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = () => {
            set_window_touched((touched) => touched + 1);
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", handler);
        return () => {
            // This is the cleanup function
            window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            This window has been touched {window_touched} times
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @tkausl - Wow, can't believe I forgot to update that. Thank you for flagging it up!! That's what I get for skipping my usual live example... :-)